# R - Converting a text file with white spaces / tabs and newline to list

Tags: r, list, parsing

Curious if you might offer advice on the following.

I have data in a text file in this form:

```
"var1"
"    var1a"
"        var1a_descrp1"
"            thing"
"    var1b"
"        var1b_descrp2"
"            thing"
"        var1b_descrp3"
"            thing1"
"            thing2"
"        var1b_descrp4"
"poobarvar"    
"    var2a"
"        var2a_descrp1"
"    var2b"
"        var2b_descrp1"
"            thing"
"        var2b_descrp1"
"            thing1"
"            thing2"
"            thing3"
```

White spaces go a max depth of 12 spaces, or "three levels" deep.

And I'd love to cleanly parse this into a list structure of something like the following structure:

```
$var1
$var1$var1a
$var1$var1a$var1a_descrp1
$var1$var1a$var1a_descrp1[[1]]
[1] "thing"



$var1$var2a
$var1$var2a$var2a_descrp2
$var1$var2a$var2a_descrp2[[1]]
[1] "thing"


$var1$var2a$var2a_descrp3
$var1$var2a$var2a_descrp3[[1]]
[1] "thing1"

$var1$var2a$var2a_descrp3[[2]]
[1] "thing2"




$poobarvar
$poobarvar$var2a
list()

$poobarvar$var2b
$poobarvar$var2b$var2b_descrp1
$poobarvar$var2b$var2b_descrp1[[1]]
[1] "thing1"

$poobarvar$var2b$var2b_descrp1[[2]]
[1] "thing2"

$poobarvar$var2b$var2b_descrp1[[3]]
[1] "thing3"
```

I have a pretty convoluted set of while loops and if-else statements I'd love to clean up.